# how to get series name when clicking any stacked column chart in anychart?

Tags: reactjs, anychart

I need the name of series when I clicked in any stacked column chart below is the code:

```
series=chart.column(thirdSeriesData);
setupSeriesLabels(series, "Requirements Complete");
series.fill("green");
series.listen("pointClick", function (e) {
console.log(e.iterator.get("value"));
console.log(e.iterator.get("name"));
console.log(e.iterator.get("x"));
});
```

note: when I click I am getting value and index and series name is undefined but I also want the series name here 'requirements complete' is my series how I will do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are applying series name using `name()` function, then you can get the series name from the event object in the same listener.
For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/ebC5evgo/0) and pay attention to lines 17 and 32-36.